# Multivariate and Multi Time Series in BigQuery ML

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-automl

I need to create a prediction of sales, for each category. Also, I know that there are some "events" with peak sales, in some dates.
I was trying to use the following bigquery regressions:

```
    ARIMA PLUS :       Univariate      Multi Time Series
    ARIMA PLUS XREG:   Multivariate    Single Time Series
```

Is there any simple model that can combine multivariable but for multi time series?
I was thinking using the ARIMA PLUS XREG multiple times.. but there are about 300 series and definitely is not the best idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The multivariate model does not support multiple time series yet. For your case with special event, this "custom holiday" feature is designed for that:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/customized-holiday-modeling-with-bigquery-ml-forecasting It can handle the peak sales for the special dates.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work! I'm gonna try it

Comment: Could you please tell me where is it mentioned that multivariate model does not support multiple time series? I'm been trying to model multiple time series using `ARIMA_PLUS_XREG` and it seemed to work at the beginning but when I perform `ML.FORECAST` the multivariate id column is not included. I thought it was a mistake from Google but your comment might explain the reason :(

Comment: I guess "it seemed to work" because the id column is treated as a feature column.